# Jmeter: How to generate HTML Dashboard in Java

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to execute Jmeter with Java so as to integrate Performance/Load Testing with Jmeter within our Test Automation Framework.
I did some research and found (successfully able to execute as well) the code mentioned below.

I'm stuck with the dashboard results. I looked it up on the internet but wasn't able to find anything regarding how can I generate the HTML Dashboard Report of Jmeter with Java.

```
package JmeterJava;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;

public class Jmeter {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        // JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();


        // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/Path/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/Path/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/");
        //JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // Initialize JMeter SaveService
        SaveService.loadProperties();

        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/Path/Test-Plan.jmx"));

      //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
        // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }


        // Store execution results into a .jtl file
        String logFile = "/Path/results.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
        
        // Run JMeter Test
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines to the end of your code:

```
JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.classname", "org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter");
JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir","report-output/dashboard");

ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator("/Path/results.jtl", null);
generator.generate();
```

And upon the next execution you will see the HTML Reporting Dashboard under `report-output/dashboard` folder

More information:

- [ReportGenerator](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/report/dashboard/ReportGenerator.html)
- [Generating Report Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. I tried your code and got this error:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot read test results file : index.html
 at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.<init>(ReportGenerator.java:134)
 at JmeterJava.Jmeter.main(Jmeter.java:53)"

Comment: I changed null to logger in: "ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator("index.html", logger);" and got this error,
"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jmeter.report.core.SampleException: Could not read metadata !
 at org.apache.jmeter.report.core.CsvSampleReader.readMetadata(CsvSampleReader.java:174)
 at org.apache.jmeter.report.core.CsvSampleReader.<init>(CsvSampleReader.java:119)
 at org.apache.jmeter.report.core.CsvSampleReader.<init>(CsvSampleReader.java:87) (Part 1/2)

Comment: at org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource.<init>(CsvFileSampleSource.java:113)
 at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:211)
 at JmeterJava.Jmeter.main(Jmeter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File is empty
 at org.apache.jmeter.report.core.CsvSampleReader.readMetadata(CsvSampleReader.java:144)" (Part 2/2)

Comment: It was a copy-paste issue, try `new ReportGenerator("/Path/results.jtl", null);`